# Why should I use continue as opposed to an empty if statement?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, continue

For example:
What is the disadvantage/advantage of using this block:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if(i < 9){}
   else Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

As opposed to this block:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if(i < 9)
   {
   continue;
   }
   Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

Considering their output is exactly the same.

Comment: There is no advantage one over the other.. With empty if, you are making it hard to read (sometimes).. you should better be using `if(i >= 9){ ..}`

Comment: BTW in your example it just prints 9 because loop is just up to 10.

Comment: Maybe someone with knowledge of what the compiler does with the continue keyword could give some advice. I dont know but continue could have some performance dis/advantage.

Comment: @Andre they dont have performance disadvantage. nor advantage. performance difference would be near epsilon ;)

Comment: Only readability. Decide by yourself or your team which approach is more readable

Comment: For readability, you can use something a little less imperative:  `foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0,11).Where(i => i >= 9))
  Console.WriteLine(i);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Empty blocks are weird, so in this case, you would just invert the condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if (i >= 9)
       Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

But in the general case, using `continue` or `break` is a good way to prevent your code from being indented too many levels. For some discussion on that topic, see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) on Programmers SE.

Comment: indented code makes more sense than indented program

Answer (score 3):

I always do

```
// ...
if(!(i < 9))
    Console.Writeline(i);
// ...
```

to prevent an empty if statement.

In your code, there is little difference between the two, with the first it doesn't reach the else statement, and the second it skips over the rest in the loop.

Comment: And as poke correctly said, it's a good way to prevent your program from being indented too many levels.

Comment: In my opinion negative `If` blocks are less readable then positive

Comment: True, but when I have an empty if statement I find it often times useful to just do a not if statement instead. Sometimes my brain isn't working, or I would have to add more logic to the if statement to get it to work without doing NOT

Comment: Negative if can be replaced by positive with `return`, `continue` or `break`. -> `if (i < 9) return; `

Comment: I guess it's personal opinion, just personally I don't like putting an 'empty' if statement (one that does nothing besides return/continue/break)

Comment: with `return`, `break` you haven't empty blocks. Consider this code: `if(i<9) continue; Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());` - will print only values which more or equal to 9, without empty blocks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95816/discussion-between-riley-carney-and-fabio).

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I find to chose one over the other is legibility. I personally use both forms, opting for one or another based more on the length of the block after the `if`. For example, if it contains a few lines only I just use the plain `if`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if (i >= 9)
       Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

(example taken from [poke answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33846302/2557263)).

But if the work is considerable, I would invert the condition and rely on `continue` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if (i < 9) continue;

   Console.Writeline(i);
   Console.Writeline("this");
   Console.Writeline("that");
   Console.Writeline("blablabla");
   Console.Writeline("hello");
   Console.Writeline("world");
   Console.Writeline(i + 1);
   Console.Writeline(i + 2);
}
```

Doing so avoids the indentation on a much bigger block. Doing on a single or very few lines is generally easy to read, but on a longer block can become more difficult to follow.